# How do I profile a WaitHandle?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, profiling, dottrace

I have the following code to index documents into ElasticSearch and want to see what takes the most time.

```
    private void DoIndex(IEnumerable<TDocument> documents, LanguageCode languageCode, ElasticSettings elasticSettings, string indexName, List<Exception> errors)
    {
        var waitHandle = new CountdownEvent(1);

        var bulkAll = ElasticClient.BulkAll(Project(documents, languageCode), b => b
            .BackOffRetries(elasticSettings.BulkBackOffRetries)
            .BackOffTime(elasticSettings.BulkBackOffTime)
            .RefreshOnCompleted()
            .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(elasticSettings.BulkThreadCount)
            .Refresh(Refresh.False)
            .Size(500)
            .Index(indexName));

        bulkAll.Subscribe(new BulkAllObserver(
            onError: exception =>
            {
                errors.Add(exception);

                Log.Error(exception, "ES indexing failed for batch.");
            },
            onCompleted: () => waitHandle.Signal(),
            onNext: response =>
            {
                Logger.Log($"Processed {response.Page * 500} documents");
            }));


        waitHandle.Wait(CancellationToken);
    }
```

When I attach a profiler (dotTrace in my case) I see that 99% of the time is spent inside the `Wait` function of my code. Somewhat understandable since that's where my code is waiting to be finished but very hard for me to find out where all my time is going.

The threads are waiting for almost 100%, I see no activity whatsoever:
[image: The threads are waiting for almost 100%]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure of understanding your question, but what your are doing is waiting for elasticsearch to respond from your bulk request. Since indexing documents is much more heavier than sending a request the results are coherent. If you want to find out what is taking time for elasticsearch, you need to monitor your elasticsearch cluster.

Comment: @Pierre-NicolasMougel I've since found why it was taking so long (ES rejecting documents due to invalid mapping), but I still don't know how to profile where the time goes. As far as I can see in dotTrace my application is just waiting 95% of the time.